# Openmodelica boundary condition is variable - mass flow

Tags: variables, modelica, openmodelica, boundary

I'm trying to model a system whose output has a variable consumption of a gas (H2). That is, the output boundary condition is variable, the mass leaving the system varies with time.

I use a Modelica.Blocks.Sources.CombiTimeTable to plot mass consumption over time.

I don't know which component I can select to model a variable boundary condition that receives information from the created table.

I just found components that can provide a variable amount of mass to the system.